# Searching for database for Colorado soils that goes back to 1990's

Tags: soil, database

Are there any database for the soils database out there beside NRCS ? I am fully aware that NRCS has their database on their website but I was wondering if there is one that can't i find them ? I am looking more specific for Colorado. They can be either database or geospatial but I prefer them to be the database that goes back to 1990's They need to have mapunit, map name, and their survey areas ?